# XML FILE LINE BREAKS

Tags: java, xml, notepad++

I am trying to use out writer in Java to create a XML file, but the generated XML File is in one line, which is very difficult to read and debug. I tried using backward-slash-n but the reader which I am using does not recognizes backward-slash-n so I need some alternative to break or backward-slash-n to add a line break to make it more readable and debug easily.

What should i do?

And also in notepad is there a way to add linebreaks using replace keyword for e.g., Search for > and replace with > + {Enter Key} i.e., line-break after every tag

Comment: "What should i do?" Well you should start by showing us the code you're using to generate the file...

Comment: I would start with changing forward slash to backward one...

Comment: <pre><code>out.write("<id>" + contractRestCount + "</id>");
    out.write("<code>" + contractRestCount + "</code>");
    out.write("<description>" + circleName.substring(0, 4)
      + "</description>");</code></pre>

Comment: @rocky i have did that already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In notepad++, you can search for

```
>
```

and replace with

```
>\r\n
```

just click the "Extended" search mode

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you do it, the text might be escaped twice. Try replacing `\n` with `\\n`.

As for the notepad part of the question I am very sure that it is not possible. I recommend Notepad++ (http://notepad-plus-plus.org). It supports this and many other functionalities, such as macros, converting between encodings, search/replace by regexp etc.